# Text files or Strings (Advice Needed)

Tags: android, database

I have too much of data to be stored and am looking for a proper way to store them.
I can use strings-arrays or text files. 
Either way, what I want to do can be accomplished but I am looking for a better way considering app speed and size.

I am thinking of using string-arrays ( a lot of).Will this be a good decision?

I want to make my app offline and that's the reason of not using Firebase.
Consider an example of all the trains and their route stations.
 So I need a perfect advice by which the thing I am looking for can easily be done.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: you should use sqlite, although ur requirements ain't very clear, but for storing large amount of data use sqlite or maybe some ORM for android.

Comment: Requirements are to store data like distance, fare, id, bus no, stops.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar String data . No problem for SQLITE

Comment: go for a database then, raw SQLite is hard to maintain, either use new Architecture Components or maybe some ORM. Also properly design your tables first, before starting implementation.

Comment: What kind of database? Will that be offline? Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your data into **SQLITE**.

> **[SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)** provides an easy and efficient way to deal with data rather than do the data processing internally inside in-memory
>   variables.

1. **I want to make my app offline** - Data storing is very easy and efficient in SQLite. Sqlite offers **OFFLINE** Mode.
2. **Considering app speed and size** - No problem. Loading data from an **`SQLite database is  faster than`** loading data out of individual files .